# Using multiple validation sets with keras

Tags: validation, keras, monitoring

I am training a model with keras using the `model.fit()` method. 
I would like to use multiple validation sets that should be validated on separately after each training epoch so that i get one loss value for each validation set. If possible they should be both displayed during training and as well be returned by the `keras.callbacks.History()` callback.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
history = model.fit(train_data, train_targets,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=[
                        (validation_data1, validation_targets1), 
                        (validation_data2, validation_targets2)],
                    shuffle=True)
```

I currently have no idea how to implement this. Is it possible to achieve this by writing my own `Callback`? Or how else would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I ended up writing my own `Callback` based on the `History` callback to solve the problem. I'm not sure if this is the best approach but the following `Callback` records losses and metrics for the training and validation set like the `History` callback as well as losses and metrics for additional validation sets passed to the constructor.

```py
class AdditionalValidationSets(Callback):
    def __init__(self, validation_sets, verbose=0, batch_size=None):
        """
        :param validation_sets:
        a list of 3-tuples (validation_data, validation_targets, validation_set_name)
        or 4-tuples (validation_data, validation_targets, sample_weights, validation_set_name)
        :param verbose:
        verbosity mode, 1 or 0
        :param batch_size:
        batch size to be used when evaluating on the additional datasets
        """
        super(AdditionalValidationSets, self).__init__()
        self.validation_sets = validation_sets
        for validation_set in self.validation_sets:
            if len(validation_set) not in [3, 4]:
                raise ValueError()
        self.epoch = []
        self.history = {}
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.epoch = []
        self.history = {}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        self.epoch.append(epoch)

        # record the same values as History() as well
        for k, v in logs.items():
            self.history.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

        # evaluate on the additional validation sets
        for validation_set in self.validation_sets:
            if len(validation_set) == 3:
                validation_data, validation_targets, validation_set_name = validation_set
                sample_weights = None
            elif len(validation_set) == 4:
                validation_data, validation_targets, sample_weights, validation_set_name = validation_set
            else:
                raise ValueError()

            results = self.model.evaluate(x=validation_data,
                                          y=validation_targets,
                                          verbose=self.verbose,
                                          sample_weight=sample_weights,
                                          batch_size=self.batch_size)

            for metric, result in zip(self.model.metrics_names,results):
                valuename = validation_set_name + '_' + metric
                self.history.setdefault(valuename, []).append(result)
```

which i am then using like this:

```py
history = AdditionalValidationSets([(validation_data2, validation_targets2, 'val2')])
model.fit(train_data, train_targets,
          epochs=epochs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          validation_data=(validation_data1, validation_targets1),
          callbacks=[history]
          shuffle=True)
```

Comment: In the latest version of Keras,  `self.model.metrics[i-1]` is a string. The `__name__` is no longer necessary (and will generate an error).

Comment: Would you consider making this into a python package? Or I can do that, if you don't have the time.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti The reason why I did not make a package out of it is, that in almost every project I slightly modify the callback (for example to support data generators).
It is not the best workflow to copy and paste the code from one project to another but it is a bit easier and, as you have guessed, I do not have the time to make a package out of it (unless you want to wait a month or so).
Feel free to make a package out of it if you have the time.
I added my GitHub username to my Account, so that you could add me the project if you want.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please share the variation of this code that supports data generators?

Comment: @cheesus A work in progress version of the package can be found on github, the code is too large to share it here. https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/keras_validation_sets

Answer (score 5):

I tested this on TensorFlow 2 and it worked. You can evaluate on as many validation sets as you want at the end of each epoch:

```
class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        res_eval_1 = self.model.evaluate(X_test_1, y_test_1, verbose = 0)
        res_eval_2 = self.model.evaluate(X_test_2, y_test_2, verbose = 0)
        print(res_eval_1)
        print(res_eval_2)
```

And later:

```
my_val_callback = MyCustomCallback()
# Your model creation code
model.fit(..., callbacks=[my_val_callback])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the current [keras docs](https://keras.io/models/model/), you can pass callbacks to `evaluate` and `evaluate_generator`. So you can call `evaluate` multiple times with different datasets.

I have not tested it, so I am happy if you comment your experiences with it below.

Comment: My specific use case was to evaluate on multiple datasets after each training epoch without having to only train one epoch at a time in a loop. If you are calling `evaluate` explicitly, then there should be no problem with calling it once for each dataset, so you don't need a callback there.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets Say your Data and pre processing is like**

```
# Model / data parameters
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

# Load the data and split it between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_valid, y_valid) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
y_train_cp = y_train
y_valid_cp = y_valid

# Scale images to the [0, 1] range
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_valid = x_valid.astype("float32") / 255
# Make sure images have shape (28, 28, 1)
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_valid = np.expand_dims(x_valid, -1)
print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], "train samples")
print(x_valid.shape[0], "validation samples")


# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_valid = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_valid, num_classes)
```

You can **create multiple validation** like

```
_, x_train_subset, _, y_train_subset = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
    validationMasks = {}
for i in range(0,10):
    validationMasks[i] = y_valid_cp==i

#Modified Train to Evaluate Over fitting
validationSets = {}

validationSets['train_sub'] = datagen_valid.flow(x_train_subset,y_train_subset)

# Specail Case Validation
#y_valid[validationMasks[randomDigit]]
validationSets['1'] = datagen_train.flow(x_valid[validationMasks[1]],y_valid[validationMasks[1]]) #Least confusing
validationSets['0'] = datagen_train.flow(x_valid[validationMasks[0]],y_valid[validationMasks[0]]) 
validationSets['6'] = datagen_train.flow(x_valid[validationMasks[6]],y_valid[validationMasks[6]])
validationSets['8'] = datagen_train.flow(x_valid[validationMasks[8]],y_valid[validationMasks[8]])
```

Now, You can use a **Custom Call Back** as

```
class MultipleValidationCallBack(keras.callbacks.Callback):

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    for thisValidationType in validationSets:
        #datagen = 
        thisLoss = self.model.evaluate(validationSets[thisValidationType])
        logs[thisValidationType+"_loss"] = thisLoss[0]
        logs[thisValidationType+"_acc"] = thisLoss[1]
```

**Model Fit can be like**,

```
modelLog = getModel().fit(
        datagenFlow_train,validation_data=datagenFlow_valid,
        callbacks=[MultipleValidationCallBack()], #
        epochs=5)
historyDf = pd.DataFrame(modelLog.history)
historyDf[['train_sub_loss','val_loss','0_loss','1_loss']].plot()
```

For Details, please refer, [End to End workable code](https://github.com/Gelesh/Multiple_Validation_Set/blob/main/Multiple_Validation_Call_Back.ipynb) and for explanation [A post on medium](https://medium.com/@gelesh.hadoop/effective-plot-and-evaluation-of-models-over-fitting-b9ee6641660e)